# Angular Resolve Scope Issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a junior developer and have been learning the ins and outs of Angular.js. I recently started using the resolve feature of the route provider to get my Project data from my service before the page loads. Before that I was calling my service inside the controller to get the data. My problem is that when I use resolve, the data gets to the controller just fine, but my scope doesn't take in my functions present at the bottom of the code and I'm not particularly sure why. If I move the function declarations to the top it works fine. My guess is that since the page now loads with the data, it doesn't have time to check the entire controller and instead just runs down it in order. Can anyone confirm why it's occurring and a solution so I can keep my code nice and readable? Thanks

My Route Provider

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/details/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/HtmlViews/Details.html',
        controller: 'detailController',
        resolve: {
            project: function (projectService, $rootScope, $route) {
                $rootScope.loading = true;
                return projectService.getProjectById($route.current.params.id);
            }
        }
    });
}])
```

My Controller (stripped to just the important stuff) In it's state below, the program can't find function getDateAt in the scope when it needs to.

```
.controller('detailController', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, projectService, project) {
    $rootScope.loading = false;
    $scope.id = project.ID;
    $scope.project = project;
    $scope.sprintCountRounded = projectService.roundSprintCount($scope.project.SprintCount, $scope.project.RoundUp);
    // Check and alter data depending on if a start date is present on the project
    $scope.isDateMissing = $scope.project.StartDate === undefined || $scope.project.StartDate === null;
    if (!$scope.isDateMissing) {

        $scope.startDate = $scope.getDateAt(0);
        $scope.finalSprintStart = $scope.getDateAt($scope.sprintCountRounded);
        $scope.finalSprintEnd = $scope.getDateAt($scope.sprintCountRounded + 1);
    }
    $scope.NumberOfLoggedSprints = $scope.project.Sprints.length;
    $scope.getDateAt = function (sprintNum) {
        return projectService.getDateAt(sprintNum, $scope.project.SprintDuration, $scope.project.StartDate);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript processes code 'top down' (somewhat), so to speak, as it is an interpreted language. So as your code is processed line by line, once it reaches the lines inside your conditional that have `$scope.getDateAt()`, it attempts to call the function on your scope object. But the problem is this: your function hasn't been defined yet, as JavaScript hasn't processed the line where your function is defined.

As you noticed, by placing your function definition at the top, it works perfectly fine, as that code is processed first. This typically happens when you declare inline functions.

The exception to this is explicit function definitions. Were you to do the following code instead, it would work regardless of where you place the `getDateAt()` function:

```
function getDateAt(sprintNum) {
    return projectService.getDateAt(sprintNum, $scope.project.SprintDuration, $scope.project.StartDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, that makes a lot of sense. Do I loose anything moving from scope declaration to explicit declaration of my function?

Comment: The one thing you lose is the scope definition of the function. If you have any template-based calls to your function (such as with `ng-click`), you'd have to create a scope based wrapper to your function. Or instead of doing that, you can simply just have all your inline function definitions be at the beginning of your controller.